# Python: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, classification

I am trying to do the machine learning practice problem of Loan Prediction from Analytics Vidhya. When I am using a Random Forest Classifier, it shows:

> TypeError:float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'

Code:

```
train['Loan_Status']=np.where(train['Loan_Status']=='Y', 1,0)

train_test_data=[train,test]

#Gender Feature
for dataset in train_test_data:
  dataset["Gender"]=dataset["Gender"].fillna('Male')
for dataset in train_test_data:
  dataset["Gender"]=dataset["Gender"].map({ "Female" : 1 , "Male" : 0}).astype(int)

#Married Feature 
for dataset in train_test_data:
  dataset['Married']=dataset['Married'].fillna('Yes')
for dataset in train_test_data:
  dataset['Married']=dataset['Married'].map({"Yes" : 1 , "No" : 0}).astype(int)

#Education Feature
for dataset in train_test_data:
  dataset['Education']=dataset['Education'].map({'Graduate' : 1 , 'Not Graduate' : 0}).astype(int)

#Combine Applicant income and coapplicant income
for dataset in train_test_data:
dataset['Income']=dataset['ApplicantIncome']+dataset['CoapplicantIncome']
train['IncomeBand']= pd.cut(train['Income'] , 4)
print(train[['IncomeBand' , 'Loan_Status']].groupby(['IncomeBand'] , as_index=False).mean())

for dataset in train_test_data:
  dataset.loc[dataset['Income'] <= 21331.5, 'Income'] =0
  dataset.loc[(dataset['Income'] > 21331.5) & (dataset['Income'] <= 41221.0), 'Income'] =1
  dataset.loc[(dataset['Income'] > 41221.0) & (dataset['Income'] <= 61110.5), 'Income'] =2
  dataset.loc[dataset['Income'] > 61110.5, 'Income'] =3
  dataset['Income']=dataset['Income'].astype(int)

# Loan Amount Feature
fillin=train.LoanAmount.median()
for dataset in train_test_data:
  dataset['LoanAmount']=dataset['LoanAmount'].fillna(fillin)
train['LoanAmountBand']=pd.cut(train['LoanAmount'] , 4)
print(train[['LoanAmountBand' , 'Loan_Status']].groupby(['LoanAmountBand'] , as_index=False).mean())

for dataset in train_test_data:
  dataset.loc[dataset['LoanAmount'] <= 181.75, 'LoanAmount'] =0
  dataset.loc[(dataset['LoanAmount'] >181.75) & (dataset['LoanAmount'] <= 354.5), 'LoanAmount'] =1
  dataset.loc[(dataset['LoanAmount'] > 354.5) & (dataset['LoanAmount'] <= 527.25), 'LoanAmount'] =2
  dataset.loc[dataset['LoanAmount'] > 527.25, 'LoanAmount'] =3
  dataset['LoanAmount']=dataset['LoanAmount'].astype(int)

#Loan Amount Term Feature
for dataset in train_test_data:
       dataset['Loan_Amount_Term']=dataset['Loan_Amount_Term'].fillna(360.0)

Loan_Amount_Term_mapping={360.0 : 1 , 180.0 : 2 , 480.0 : 3 , 300.0 : 4 , 84.0 : 5 , 240.0 : 6, 120.0 :7 , 36.0:8 , 60.0 : 9, 12.0 :10}

for dataset in train_test_data:
              dataset['Loan_Amount_Term']=dataset['Loan_Amount_Term'].map(Loan_Amount_Term_mapping)

# Credit History Feature
for dataset in train_test_data:
  dataset['Credit_History']=dataset['Credit_History'].fillna(2)

# Property Area Feature
for dataset in train_test_data:
 dataset['Property_Area']=dataset['Property_Area'].map({'Semiurban' : 0 , 'Urban' : 1 , 'Rural' : 2}).astype(int)

# Feature Selection
features_drop=['Self_Employed' , 'ApplicantIncome' , 'CoapplicantIncome', 'Dependents']
train=train.drop(features_drop, axis=1)
test=test.drop(features_drop, axis=1)
train.drop(['Loan_ID' , 'IncomeBand' , 'LoanAmountBand'] , axis=1)

X_train=train.drop('Loan_Status' , axis=1)
y_train=train['Loan_Status']
X_test=test.drop('Loan_ID' , axis=1).copy()

X_train.shape , y_train.shape , X_test.shape

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_random_forest = clf.predict(X_test)
acc_random_forest = round(clf.score(X_train, y_train) * 100, 2)
print (acc_random_forest)
```

[image: X_train.dtypes]

I don't understand from where the float error is coming from. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try running `X.train.dtypes` and add the result here. It would also help if you minimized the code to illustrate the problem, see [mcve].

Comment: Which line is the float error happening on?

Comment: @doctorlove the float error is happening on clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

Comment: @Shaido Thank you for your suggestion. I've added the result of X_train. types

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue are the columns with the category data type.
These can for example be created with the `pd.cut` function. The random forest classifier can not take these as input, so you need to convert them to numbers instead.

This can easiest be done by using `cat.codes`.

In the code above, the two columns `IncomeBand` and `LoanAmountBand` need to be changed from category to numbers:

```
train['IncomeBand']= pd.cut(train['Income'] , 4).cat.codes
train['LoanAmountBand']=pd.cut(train['LoanAmount'] , 4).cat.codes
```

Comment: Thank you the error was fixed but now I got this error : could not convert string to float: 'LP002990'. LP002990 is the Loan_ID in the train dataset. I already dropped Loan_ID in the above codes. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @ALT: From your `X_train.dtypes` you can see that the column is still there. You can add `inplace=True` when calling `drop`, otherwise you need to assign the output 5he a new variable.